# React native Deeplinking using expo v40.0.0

Tags: javascript, react-native

How to link web to the app using deep linking  in React native using expo without navigation

Answer (score 0):

add styles

```
import {Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Linking, } from 'react-native'

function App() {
return(
 <View>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>{Linking.openURL(url)}}>
       <Text>www.example.com</Text> 
    </TouchableOpacity>
 </View>
)}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for you answer but my question Is I want to click a button on web page and redirect to app specific screen using expo without navigation